# RecyclerView: получение доступа к элементам

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Есть recyclerview, каждый элемент которого содержит в себе пару тектовых полей и кнопку. С помощью адаптера это все дело заполняется:

```
public class RVAdapterStart extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapterStart.TaskViewHolder> {
public static class TaskViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    private TextView title;
    private TextView status;
    private Button button;

    TaskViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        status = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.status);
        button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.tasks_finish);
    }
}

private List<Task> tasksStart;

RVAdapterStart() {

}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(TaskViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.title.setText(tasksStart.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.status.setText(tasksStart.get(position).getStatus());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return tasksStart.size();
}

@Override
public TaskViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view =  LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_tasks_start, viewGroup, false);
    TaskViewHolder tvh = new TaskViewHolder(view);
    return tvh;
}
```

Как получить доступ к этим элементам из активити (нужно повесить слушателей на кнопки)?

Comment: а не лучше ли повести слушателей сразу при создании в методе `onCreateViewHolder` ?

Comment: Возможно, но тут сложнее ситуация, есть еще один recycler и они оба между собой взаимодействуют, т.е. при нажатии на кнопку в первом recycler элемент перескакивает во второй, а во втором есть кнопка отмены и при нажатии на нее элемент должен перескакивать обратно в первый. Вот я все не могу придумать, как это сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если элементы разметки одинаковые в обоих списках и представляют одинаковые данные, то вам надо лишь изменять список данных, отображаемых адаптерами.

Т.е.

1. из одного удаляем данные, в другой добавляем.
2. На обоих вызываем методы, уведомляющие об удалении/добавлении данных на определённой позиции.
3. Адаптеры сами перерисуются соответствующим образом.
4. При этом, если слушатели нажатий будут назначаться прямо в методе onBindViewHolder, то при добавлении нового элемента ему будет назначен слушатель нажатий.

Answer (score 1):

Тебе стоит создать листенер(слушателя) в `Activity` и потом передать его в адаптер. Затем для каждой кнопки создать свой `OnClickListener`, из которого будет вызываться подходящий метод в первом листенере.